# Build.SourceVersion is blank in VSO vNext Build

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using the new scriptable build features in Visual Studio Online (not the XAML build definitions), and I am trying to have the build version number include the latest Git Commit ID of the target repository using the Build Number Format.

I am using the following build number format:

```
$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(BuildId).$(SourceVersion)
```

Which results in a generated version number of `1.0.1234.` - i.e. the SourceVersion value is blank, which causes an error in VSO when queueing a build. I have also tried qualifying the variable by prefixing it with `Build.` with the same result. To test, I have changed the build number to the following format:

```
$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(BuildId).$(SourceBranch)
```

This correctly results in a value of `1.0.1234.refs_heads_master`

I have been using the [Predefined Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/scripts/variables) reference and Build.SourceVersion is listed as a Global Variable.

Am I doing something wrong, have I encountered a bug or is this by design and not available at the time the build is queued? If this is by design, is there any way to automatically include the short Git Commit ID in the Build Number Format?

This is where I set the build number format in VSO:
[image: This is where I set the build number format in VSO]

This is the error I see when I don't explicitly specify a Git CommitId:

> 400: The build number format string
>   $(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(BuildId).$(SourceVersion) generated
>   a build number 0.1.1. which contains invalid character(s), is too
>   long, or ends with '.'. The maximum length of a build number is 255
>   characters. Characters which are not allowed include '"', '/', ':',
>   '<', '>', '\', '|', '?', '@', and '*'.

Comment: I can achieve what you described with `$(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(Build.BuildId).$(Build.SourceVersion)`. Have just verified on both VSO and TFS 2015 on-premise. The output looks like this: `1.0.20.41f2983578f720695227a7a8a41ed3d7437efc30`. Are you sure it's not a typo causing that strange behavior on your side?

Comment: @YanSklyarenko, I always get the "Unable to expand the macro $(Build.SourceVersion) specified in build number format (type InvalidMacroInBuildNumberException)" exception if I use $(MajorVersion).$(MinorVersion).$(Build.BuildId).$(Build.SourceVersion) to define the build number format. In addition, the SourceVersion variable is latest version control change that is included in this build. CommitId or changeset number (CS1234, for example), which should not be something like '41f2983578f720695227a7a8a41ed3d7437efc30'. Did I miss something important?

Comment: @Vicky, hmm, that's a different thing, I suppose. Looks like that exception (`InvalidMacroInBuildNumberException`) means the build number format is invalid. I mean, it expects Major.Minor.Build.Revision all to be numbers, not those IDs and hashes. The macro part of $(Build.SourceVersion) works, but you can't use it in build number. Your other comment - commit ID in Git is that long hash, `CS1234` is the format of TFVC changeset.

Comment: @YanSklyarenko I did try both `$(Build.SourceVersion)` and just `$(SourceVersion)` and both resulted in a blank value, unless I explicitly specified the full Git Commit ID when queuing the build. Since this is for Continuous Integration, I'd need the latest Git Commit ID to be picked up automatically. Ideally, I'd like the short hash too. I should clarify that this is in the "Build Number Format" in VSO Scriptable Build (vNext) rather than XAML build definitions.

Comment: @GaryJL, now I'm confused. Perhaps, if  you make a screenshot, it would be clearer...

Comment: @YanSklyarenko Added a screenshot to the question, and the error I see when queueing the build.

Comment: Right, now I can reproduce it. It seems that the set of available tokens is different for build number format. I would say that @Vicky 's suggestion is the only possible if you have to stick with this source version approach. Alternatively, you can revise your versioning policy following [this guideline](http://incyclesoftware.com/2015/06/vnext-build-awesomeness-managing-version-numbers/) instead.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to use `$(Build.SourceVersion)`, but only when builds were triggered automatically on commit (on Continuous integration). It turns out to be empty only if I queue it manually:

[image: Build queue screenshot]

I'm using the following Build number format:

```
$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(date:yyyyMMdd)_$(Build.BuildId).$(Build.SourceVersion)$(rev:.r)
```

Comment: @MonDeveloper Yes, it fills automatically on CI-triggered builds when I use the above format string. It also seems to be possible to specify the Source Version when queuing the builds manually, see Will's answer for details.

Answer (score 3):

NeoGarRiGus - it turns out empty because when you run a manual build you have to enter the Source Version field in order for it to populate. The CI inputs that value automatically when a Dev check's in but when you queue a build manually there is a blank field in the pop-up that allows you to enter the Source Version:

[Source Version Field in VSTS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQVhA.png)

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid it is not able to use `$(SourceVersion)` in the build number format. However, I think you can use PowerShell to change build number to be `$(SourceVersion)`, and you need to include the PowerShell in your build process. Check this link for the details.

And you can define the PowerShell to be similar to:

```powershell
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Net")

[String] $CollectionUrl = "https://vsoserver.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection"
[String] $BuildUrl = $env:BUILD_BUILDURI 

$netCred = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential("username","password")
$basicCred = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.BasicAuthCredential($netCred)
$tfsCred = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsClientCredentials($basicCred)


$teamProjectCollection = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection($CollectionUrl,$tfsCred)

$buildServer = $teamProjectCollection.GetService([type]"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.IBuildServer")

$buildDetail = $buildServer.GetBuild([Uri]$BuildUrl)

$buildDetail.BuildNumber = $Env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSION 

$buildDetail.KeepForever = $true
$buildDetail.Save()
```

Comment: This looks useful. I'll keep it in mind if I don't find a solution using the predefined variables.

Comment: I would say this is the only possible solution for now.

Comment: Hi @Yan, I'm using your solution but getting error, System.InvalidOperationException : Basic authentication requires a secure connection to the server. Right on this line IBuildDetail buildDetail = buildServer.GetBuild(BuildUrl);

Comment: Well not really my solution... @vicky-msft, do you have a suggestion?