# VSO Build vNext - get TFS revision number

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-devops

In my build steps I need to provide TFS revision number as a paramter. I know there is a variable $(Build.SourceVersion) but it returns it with a "CS" prefix e.g. "CS1234"

Is there an easy way to remove that "CS" prefix? Any built-in string functions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware about any built-in functions to format that string - you'll have to do it in your script somewhere. Note that `$(Build.SourceVersion)` variable returns empty string if you specify it in the Build Number Format field in your build definition. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603712/build-sourceversion-is-blank-in-vso-vnext-build) might give you more details.

Answer (score 1):

There is no build in method.  Also changeset number and revision number are not the same thing.  You will get **COMMIT ID** in `$(Build.SourceVersion)` if you are using GIT repository.

You may use PowerShell to strip that part off.  Following line should give you the numeric portion.

`[string]$version = ($Env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSION -replace'\D+(\d+)','$1')`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @cilerler's answer, I've used this generic Powershell script as my first VSTS build step:

```
Param(
    [string] $SourceBranchName = $Env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME,
    [string] $SourceVersion = $Env:BUILD_SOURCEVERSION
)

Write-Host "SourceBranchName = $SourceBranchName"
Write-Host "SourceVersion = $SourceVersion"

if ($SourceBranchName -eq "trunk"){
    $MajorMinor = "0.0"
}
else{
    $MajorMinor = $SourceBranchName
}

# Remove CS from changeset number
$Revision = ($SourceVersion -replace 'C','')

$BuildNumber = "$MajorMinor.$Revision.0"

Write-Host "Setting Build Number '$BuildNumber'"

Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$BuildNumber"
```

Note that it presumes that your branch name is in the format `Major.Minor` (eg. `1.4`) or `trunk`.

Also, it seems the VSTS [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/build/scripts/variables#GlobalBuildVariables) is wrong, the `Build.SourceVersion` variables is of the form `C1226`.