# Naming TFS build after it starts

Tags: tfs-2015

Can I replace the Name of the build that is running after it has started ?  I want to set it to the changeset number that I get from the TFS repository.

Comment: Are you using XAML Build or vNext Build?

Comment: I'm using the new vNext build

Comment: In vNext build, the Build number format is also defined in build step before build, we can't change it when the build is running after is has started.

Comment: Refer to this question for details if you want to set the SourceVersion in build number: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603712/build-sourceversion-is-blank-in-vso-vnext-build

Answer (score 1):

**XAML Build:**

`Build number format` is defined in build process template. You can't change it when the build is running after is has started:

[image]

If you want to check changset number of this build, you can go to web access and check the `Source Version` of this build:

[image]

**vNext Build:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Regarding the build number format in vNext: is there an article on MSDN listing all variables available to be used in that field? Not all listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Build/scripts/variables) work

Comment: Agreed, I did try $(Build.SourceVersion) but that causes error when I queue up a new build