# Get Visual Studio changeset as part of the revision

Tags: c#, visual-studio, svn, tfs, version-control

For years I have been using Subversion.  My released software version numbers are in the format X.X.X.{SVN REV} and I use a pre-build event in Visual studio to populate a c# revision file:

```
namespace Revision
{
    internal static class Svnstrings
    {
        static public int WCREV = 1959;
        static public string WCDATE = "2017/12/08 21:48:52";
        static public string WCNOW = "2017/12/28 14:01:35";
        static public string WCRANGE = "1949:1959";
        static public string WCMIXED = "Mixed update revision";
        static public string WCMODS = "Modified";
        static public string WCURL = "https://app.deveo.com/SrcCtrl/projects/myProject/repositories/subversion/myProject/trunk/mySource/myProject/Revision";
        static public string WCINSVN = "Versioned";
        static public string WCNEEDSLOCK = "Lock not required";
        static public string WCISLOCKED = "Not Locked";
        static public string WCLOCKDATE = "1970/01/01 00:00:00";
        static public string WCLOCKOWNER = "";
        static public string WCLOCKCOMMENT = "";
    }
}
```

I recently switched to Visual Studio TFS for my source control and I would like to do something similar, grab the changeset value in WCREV.

Maybe this over over complicated but still learning the new source control after using Subversion for 10+ years and still learning the basics and maybe someone has a better idea.

Comment: We use a TFS extension called "Assembly Info" to set the changeset number on the assembly in the TFS build definition. We don't set it in the code anywhere, but we do reference whatever the current assembly version is in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike SVN, we do not have `WCREV.exe` installed along with TFS.

In TFS the simplest way is using the build number as your version number. There is  a Global .NET Versioning Strategy: ***AssemblyInformationalVersion***. You could use this strategy to add versioning to your software. You could use a [powershell script](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/scripts/index#example-version-your-assemblies) to version to your assemblies.

> The powershell script will do the magic in the background to replace
>   all versioning values for *AssemblyVersion*, *AssemblyFileVersion* and
>   *AssemblyInformationalVersion* in the Assembly Info files, based on this product version. The product version will be passed as a whole to
>   the AssemblyVersion and the AssemblyInformationalVersion attributes.
>   The AssemblyFileVersion will be replaced with a full version number
>   which will consist of the major and minor version number of the
>   product version, a Julian based date and an **incremental build number**.

[image]

> For the meaning of Assembly File Version = *2.7.15169.03*
>
> - 2 => taken from “Major” product version
> - 7 => taken from “Minor” product version
> - 15169 => generated by build process: “15” = year 2015, “169” = day of    year 2015
> - 3 => third build, run on day 169 in year 2015

For more details you could take a look at this great post: [TFS Build 2015 … and versioning!](https://intovsts.net/2015/08/24/tfs-build-2015-and-versioning/) and this similar topic [vNext Build Awesomeness – Managing Version Numbers](http://blogs.incyclesoftware.com/2015/06/vnext-build-awesomeness-managing-version-numbers/)

---

As for you want to get/set changeset number in your Assembly  info.

You could use `$(Build.SourceVersion)` in your build number format to achieve this, such as

`$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(date:yyyyMMdd)_$(Build.BuildId).$(Build.SourceVersion)$(rev:.r)`

However this $(Build.SourceVersion) only works when builds were triggered automatically on commit (on Continuous integration).Cause when you run a manual build you have to enter the Source Version field in order for it to populate. More details please check this: [Build.SourceVersion is blank in VSO vNext Build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603712/build-sourceversion-is-blank-in-vso-vnext-build)

You could also use PowerShell script to get the Source Version Changeset number  and apply it in your build number or AssemblyInfo.

Comment: TFS is using `$(Rev:.rr)` to ensure that every completed build has a unique name. When a build is completed, if nothing else in the build number has changed, the Rev integer value is incremented by one automatically. Source Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/concepts/definitions/build/options#build-number-format